# how to create a portal user for my test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
   Profile profile1 = [Select Id from Profile where name = 'GHI Portal User'];
    User portalAccountOwner1 = new User(
    ProfileId = profile1.Id,
    Username ='test2@test.com',
    Alias = 'batman',
    Email='bruce.wayne@wayneenterprises.com',
    EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
    Firstname='Bruce',
    Lastname='Wayne',
    LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
    LocaleSidKey='en_US',
    TimeZoneSidKey='America/Chicago'
    );
    insert portalAccountOwner1;


    System.runAs ( portalAccountOwner1 ) {
    //Create account
    Account portalAccount1 = new Account(
    Name = 'TestAccount',
    OwnerId = portalAccountOwner1.Id
    );
    insert portalAccount1;

    //Create contact
    Contact contact1 = new Contact(
    FirstName = 'Test',
    Lastname = 'McTesty',
    AccountId = portalAccount1.Id,
    Email = 'test@test.com'
    );
    insert contact1;

    //Create user
    Profile portalProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile Limit 1];
    User user1 = new User(
    Username = 'test12345@test.com',
    ContactId = contact1.Id,
    ProfileId = portalProfile.Id,
    Alias = 'test123',
    Email = 'test12345@test.com',
    EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
    LastName = 'McTesty',
    CommunityNickname = 'test12345',
    TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
    LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
    LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
    );
    insert user1;
    update user1;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can follow the detailed tutorial [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Testing_with_RunAs). The key points to note are

- The user that creates the portal user MUST have a Role.
- `getPortalUser()` returns a reference to portal user
- You then use this reference with `runAs()` to check whether Portal permissions are enabled or not

`

```
@IsTest enum PortalType { CSPLiteUser, PowerPartner, PowerCustomerSuccess, CustomerSuccess }
static testmethod void usertest() {
    User pu = getPortalUser(PortalType.PowerPartner, null, true);
    System.assert([select isPortalEnabled
                     from user
                    where id = :pu.id].isPortalEnabled,
                  'User was not flagged as portal enabled.');      
    System.RunAs(pu) {
        System.assert([select isPortalEnabled
                         from user
                        where id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].isPortalEnabled,
                      'User wasnt portal enabled within the runas block. ');
    }
}

    public static User getPortalUser(PortalType portalType, User userWithRole, Boolean doInsert) {

        /* Make sure the running user has a role otherwise an exception
           will be thrown. */
        if(userWithRole == null) {  
            if(UserInfo.getUserRoleId() == null) {
                UserRole r = new UserRole(name = 'TEST ROLE');
                Database.insert(r);
                userWithRole = new User(alias = 'hasrole', email='userwithrole@roletest1.com', userroleid = r.id,
                                    emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                                    localesidkey='en_US', profileid = UserInfo.getProfileId(),
                                    timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', 36
            } else {
                userWithRole = new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId(), UserRoleId = UserInfo.getUserRoleId());
            }
            System.assert(userWithRole.userRoleId != null,
                          'This test requires the target org to have at least one UserRole created. Please create a user role in this organization and try again.');
        }
        Account a;
        Contact c;
        System.runAs(userWithRole) {
            a = new Account(name = 'TEST ACCOUNT');
            Database.insert(a);
            c = new Contact(AccountId = a.id, lastname = 'lastname');
            Database.insert(c);
        }
        /* Get any profile for the given type.*/
        Profile p = [select id
                      from profile
                     where usertype = :portalType.name()
                     limit 1];  
        String testemail = 'puser000@amamama.com';
        User pu = new User(profileId = p.id, username = testemail, email = testemail,
                           emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', localesidkey = 'en_US',
                           languagelocalekey = 'en_US', timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                           alias='cspu', lastname='lastname', contactId = c.id);
        if(doInsert) {
            Database.insert(pu);
        }
        return pu;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following codes

```
Set<String> customerUserTypes = new Set<String> {'CSPLiteUser', 'PowerPartner', 'PowerCustomerSuccess',   'CustomerSuccess'};
        Account acc1 = new Account (
        Name = 'newAcc1'
        );  
        insert acc1;
        Contact conCase = new Contact (
        AccountId = acc1.id,
        LastName = 'portalTestUserv1'
        );
        insert conCase;
        //Create user

        Profile prfile = [select Id,name from Profile where UserType in :customerUserTypes limit 1];

        User newUser1 = new User(
        profileId = prfile.id,
        username = 'newUser@yahoo.com',
        email = 'pb@f.com',
        emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8',
        localesidkey = 'en_US',
        languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
        timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
        alias='nuser',
        lastname='lastname',
        contactId = conCase.id
        );
        insert newUser1;
```