# Test Class Error :System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: unit-test, controller

When i run the test class in Apex Test Execution,i get error for the controller as

```
Error Message   System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Stack Trace Class.Test_ApprovalProcessLeadController.sapld1: line 25, column 1

Error line is :user u =[select id,Profile_Name__c from user WHERE Profile_Name__c='Custom Partner Community user' limit 1];
```

Similarly for the test class2.

Test CLass :

```
    @isTest
public class Test_ApprovalProcessLeadController {
   Public static testMethod void sapld() {

        user u =[select id,Profile_Name__c from user  limit 1]; 
        lead l = new lead();
        l.lastname='Test';
        l.company='test';
        l.email='abc@test.com';       
        l.Approval_flag__c=false; 
        l.Rep_Managing_Partner__c= u.id;
        l.Approval_Status__c='Pending Approval';   
        insert l;
         System.AssertEquals(l.Id!=null,True);
         ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id', l.id);
         ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(l);         
         ApprovalProcessLeadController a = new ApprovalProcessLeadController(controller);
            test.startTest();
            a.getdetails();
            a.Redirect();
            test.stoptest();
        }

        Public static testMethod void sapld1() 
        {

         Account acc11 = new Account(Name='Testing SubscriptionClone', BillingStreet='Banjara hills', BillingCity='Hyd', BillingState='TS',
                                    BillingPostalCode = '500084', BillingCountry = 'India', Phone = '100', Industry = 'Banking',
                                    Type = 'Paid', Customer_Type__c = 'Customer', Customer_List__c = true);
        insert acc11 ;
        contact cc11 = new contact(FirstName ='Test Contact Subscription', LastName ='Opptyclone', Role__c='Subscription Administrator',AccountId=acc11.Id);
        insert cc11;
        Profile p = [SELECT id ,Name FROM Profile WHERE Name='Custom Partner Community user'];

        User u = new User(
            FirstName = 'test', 
            LastName= 'last_test', 
            Email='test323232@test.com', 
            Phone='111-111-1111', 
            //True_Market_Unit__c='1111', 
            alias = 'test', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
            ProfileId = p.Id,
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
            UserName = 'test323232@test.com'
            );
         u.ContactId=cc11.Id;
        insert u;


       // user u =[select id,Profile_Name__c from user WHERE Profile_Name__c='Custom Partner Community user' limit 1];
        System.AssertEquals(u.Id!=null,True);                 
        lead l = new lead();
        l.lastname='Test';
        l.company='test';
        l.email='abc@test.com';
        l.Approval_flag__c=false;
        l.Product_Interest__c='Services';
        l.Rep_Managing_Partner__c = u.id;
        l.Approval_Status__c='Pending Approval';                      
        insert l;
         ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id', l.id);
         ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(l);          
         ApprovalProcessLeadController a = new ApprovalProcessLeadController(controller);
         test.startTest();
         a.getdetails();
         a.Redirect();
         test.stoptest();
        } 

        Public static testMethod void sapld2() 
        {
        Account acc11 = new Account(Name='Testing SubscriptionClone', BillingStreet='Banjara hills', BillingCity='Hyd', BillingState='TS',
                                    BillingPostalCode = '500084', BillingCountry = 'India', Phone = '100', Industry = 'Banking',
                                    Type = 'Paid', Customer_Type__c = 'Customer', Customer_List__c = true);
        insert acc11 ;
        contact cc11 = new contact(FirstName ='Test Contact Subscription', LastName ='Opptyclone', Role__c='Subscription Administrator',AccountId=acc11.Id);
        insert cc11;
        Profile p = [SELECT id ,Name FROM Profile WHERE Name='Custom Partner Community user'];

        User u = new User(
            FirstName = 'test', 
            LastName= 'last_test', 
            Email='test323232@test.com', 
            Phone='111-111-1111', 
            //True_Market_Unit__c='1111', 
            alias = 'test', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
            ProfileId = p.Id,
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
            UserName = 'test323232@test.com'
            );
         u.ContactId=cc11.Id;
        insert u;

       // user u =[select id,Profile_Name__c from user WHERE Profile_Name__c='Custom Partner Community user' limit 1];
        System.AssertEquals(u.Id!=null,True);       
        lead l = new lead();
        l.lastname='Test';
        l.company='test';
        l.email='abc@test.com';
        l.Approval_flag__c=false;
        l.Product_Interest__c='Services';      
        l.Rep_Managing_Partner__c = u.id;                    
        insert l;
         ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id', l.id);
         ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(l);          
         ApprovalProcessLeadController a = new ApprovalProcessLeadController(controller);
         test.startTest();
         a.getdetails();
         a.Redirect();
         test.stoptest();
        }   

    }
```

Controller :

```
public with sharing  class ApprovalProcessLeadController{
    Public id getid;
    Public id userid;
    public boolean flag1{get;set;}
    Public Boolean showvalues{get;set;}
    Public Lead getdata{get;set;}

    list<Lead> getLeaddetails= new list<Lead>();

        public ApprovalProcessLeadController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){

        getdata = new Lead();
         getid = apexpages.currentpage().getParameters().get('id');
           showvalues =False;
             system.debug('ajitava133'+getid );
        }      
        public void getdetails(){
         getdata= [select id,Product_Interest__c,Total_of_Databases_in_your_Org__c,Rep_Managing_Partner__c,Approval_Status__c,CheckCreatedByProfile1__c,Approval_flag__c from Lead where id =: getid limit 1];
         System.debug('@@@@@getdata'+getdata);
            if( getdata!=null)
            {
                system.debug('@@@@@@getdata.Rep_Managing_Partner__c'+getdata.Rep_Managing_Partner__c);
                if(getdata.Rep_Managing_Partner__c !=null)
                {                                                                        
                    if(getdata.Product_Interest__c== null)
                    {
                        showvalues =True;    
                    }                                       
                  else if(getdata.Approval_Status__c == 'Pending Approval')                   
                   {
                       ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Approval request is already submitted/Approved '));
                   }

                   else if(getdata.Approval_flag__c!=true && getdata.CheckCreatedByProfile1__c==true || (getdata.Approval_Status__c =='Rejected'))
                   {
                       userid = getdata.Rep_Managing_Partner__c;
                       Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
                       req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
                       req1.setObjectId(getid);
                       req1.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{userid });
                       Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
                       flag1=true;
                   }
                   else                   
                   {                                   
                   if(getdata.Approval_flag__c==true)
                         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Approval request is already submitted/Approved '));
                         if(getdata.CheckCreatedByProfile1__c==false)

                               ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,' You dont have access to submit this lead for apporval'));                  
                   }
                }               
                else
                {               
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,' Need to enter the Rep Managing Partner in order to send approval'));                                
                }
            }

        }
      public pagereference Redirect(){

         String newPageUrl = '/'+getdata.id;
         PageReference newPage = new PageReference(newPageUrl);
            newPage.setRedirect(true);

            return newPage;                  

            }
}
```

In Developer Console ..the line which are not covered are

```
  public boolean flag1{get;set;}
if(getdata.Product_Interest__c== null)
                    {
                        showvalues =True;    
                    }                                       
                  else if(getdata.Approval_Status__c == 'Pending Approval')                   
                   {
                       ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Approval request is already submitted/Approved '));
                   }

                   else if(getdata.Approval_flag__c!=true && getdata.CheckCreatedByProfile1__c==true || (getdata.Approval_Status__c =='Rejected'))
                   {
                       userid = getdata.Rep_Managing_Partner__c;
                       Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
                       req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
                       req1.setObjectId(getid);
                       req1.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{userid });
                       Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
                       flag1=true;
                   }
                   else                   
                   {                                   
                   if(getdata.Approval_flag__c==true)
                         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Approval request is already submitted/Approved '));
                         if(getdata.CheckCreatedByProfile1__c==false)

                               ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,' You dont have access to submit this lead for apporval'));                  
                   }
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Your query is not returning any records.. You need create a user with `Profile_Name__c='Custom Partner Community user'`

Comment: @Ratan,@Prady,@Oles Malkov:Thanks for the response.The test methods got passed.By doing an insertion of account and contact .But now the code coverage remains constant .Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That error is because your query is **not** returning any records. You have to create that user first. I assume that `Profile_Name__c` is a formula field that displays the Name of assigned profile. If so, you can add this method to your test class:

```
@testSetup 
static void setupUser() {
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Custom Partner Community user'];

    User u = new User(LastName = 'testUser', Email = 'user@test.com', ProfileId = p.Id, 
                  Alias = 'test', Username = 'test@test.com', LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                  TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', 
                  LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US');
    insert u;
}
```

Comment: :Thanks for your response.When i added this in test class.it throws an error as System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Cannot create a portal user without contact: [ContactId]

Comment: Looks like this is a portal user, can you please check this link it is well explained there how to create a portal user http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65804/how-to-create-a-portal-user-for-my-test-class